# How to add clickable link on admin side in keystonejs

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

In keystonejs, I want to add a link on admin side. lets say I have type string or type url as shown, but both show text box on admin side

```
link: { type: String}
url: {type: Types.Url}
```

Is there any property that I can use to add link that open a new tab and show web page?

**Solution:**

I posted this issue on keystone github issues page as well and found the solution in link

https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/4607#issuecomment-382856648

Comment: Do you want a field on a database model to be a hyperlink?

Comment: In keystone model, to be shown on admin side. And it will become db model as well.